# element extends to end of line - can this be prevented?

Tags: html

I have a form with the following...

```
<dt class=idx><span>Sex:</span></dt><dl><fieldset>Male<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="Male" checked>Female<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="Female"></fieldset></dl>
```

the problem is that the box created by the fieldset extends to the right margin.  I'd like it to extend only as far as necessary to include the two radio buttons.  The dt, dl, and scan stuff is there to effect spacing and leaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your fieldset tag to this:

```
<fieldset style="display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  Is there anyway to modify the height of the fieldset box?

Comment: Just use `height: [number]px;`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like CSS has a width:100% in place on one of the items, you maight want to try width:auto; or display:inline;

Comment: Unfortunately, as you may not expect, `width: auto;` is the default and hence, does not change anything.